# NumberFormatter Error at Live Server

Tags: php, cpanel, numberformatter

```
  <?php
    $f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
    echo ucwords($f->format($TotalCredit));
  ?>
```

I am using this code to convert number to string. This is working fine in locally but when i upload it on live server it gives a error saying "Class 'NumberFormatter' not found".

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyE5c.jpg)

PHP Version of the server that I am using is 5.6.16. In the local server after uncommenting the line `extension=ext/php_intl.dll` it runs but why i am getting this error in live server ?

Comment: Did you do the same on the live server?

Comment: @AndrewL How to do that on server ? I searched but did not find any php.ini file.

Comment: How are you accessing the server?

Comment: On documentation it says " /usr/local/lib/ directory contains your server's php.ini file."
But i did not find anything like that when i logged into the cpanel.

Comment: Are you running a linux based OS on the server? If not then you won't find it there. Try the windows server path

Comment: Did you find my answer correct ? Can you mark it please ?

Comment: After contacting with the support team they enabled php_intl.dll and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the extension needed to use that Class, is not available on Live Server.

You **must** do `extension=ext/php_intl.dll` on Live Server.

If you cant find the `php.ini` on the Live Server, I can give you 2 options:

1. Go to `/etc/php/` and see inside if there is any `php.ini`.
2. Contact Support on your Live Server and ask them to enable `php_intl.dll` as extension.